# Angularjs, SVG, $route and ui-bootstrap Modal - url(#id) breaks

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This issue must be similar to other reported problems involving SVG patterns referenced by  `url(#fill-ID)`.  I have tried many of the suggestions found here including setting `<base>` and `html5mode`, using a directive, `$location.absUrl()` and so on.

In my situation, I have an SVG that is created using ng-repeat on an array. I want to pop this SVG into a modal using the same controller and template.  All is good until the modal is closed.  At that point the fills and other SVG elements that are added, the `url()` attributes fail.

I have created this plunk [Angular with SVG and Modal](http://plnkr.co/edit/39QrKPkN463PXKbFLkdG).  Differences between the plunk and my code are that the partial `svg.html` is located in a sub-directory off the root.

My application and plunk work just fine in Firefox and IE11, but in Chrome, the `url(#)` does not resolve and hence the fills are blank.

It seems like I am Alice chasing a rabbit down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Plunker failes when running Chrome with the error http://run.plnkr.co/GWuoERUcAxMMSBCF/template/modal/window.html 404 (Not Found).

Comment: To test in chrome, a download may be required.

Comment: Don't use `<base>` tags with SVG. The combination will cause you to cry. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase